# OnTime is not Working

Tags: vba, excel, ontime

I currently have on OnTime Function (below) that isn't working.

```
Sub DeleteAllZeros()"   'All of these are defined and work perfectly'
ApagarZerosLCA
ApagarZerosLCAFEC
ApagarZerosLCA_ACC
ApagarZerosLCA_ACC_FEC
ApagarZerosLCI
ApagarZerosLCIFEC
End Sub


Private Sub AutoDeleteZeros()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:32:00"), "DeleteAllZeros"

End Sub
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working? Also (likely dumb questions), how would I have it so that this would run if the workbook is closed? Is it possible to have it run if the computer is locked, shut down, or logged off?

Thanks!

Comment: Getting this to run while the computer is shut down would be quite a feat!  for the other cases though, you should maybe consider using Windows Task Scheduler and a `Workbook_Open` macro instead of `OnTime`.

Comment: Does it work if you change `TimeValue("15:32:00")` to `DateValue(Now() - TimeValue("15:32:00")) + TimeValue("15:32:00")`?

Comment: @Tim Williams hahahaha. I realize it was a very dumb question. But you never know. Before I started playing with VBA I had no idea that some of these things we're possible. So maybe it could work some kinda magic and turn the computer on too! haha

Comment: (Anyone coming across this in the future, the actual code you should replace with is `Int(Now() - TimeValue("15:32:00") + 1) + TimeValue("15:32:00")`.)

Answer (score 0):

Application.OnTime works in the Windows implementation. As of 3/27/2021, it does not work on an Apple Mac Mini M1.

I ran the following test code to verify it's a bug in Microsoft's VBA interpreter. The Message box never appears unless testboo is run directly.  I lifted the Ontime call from Microsoft's documentation.

```
 Sub testtime()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "testboo"
 End Sub

 Sub testboo()
   MsgBox ("boo")
 End Sub
```